# Where to put a flag for extended debugging info?

Tags: java, debugging, serialization, flags

I'm currently in trouble with serialization, but I found this nice flag which will help me debugging:

> -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true

My problem is, that after hours of research I still don't know how to use it. I tried to simply write it down in my main method, but that doesn't work.

**Where do I have to put this flag?**

I use eclipse, so I wonder if I have to edit the settings as well?

Comment: IIRC `logging.properties`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm absolutely new to this. What does IIRC mean? and what do I have to do with logging.properties? Thank you

Comment: IIRC means `if I remember correctly`. Put it in the root of the project, but I think that only works with Logger.

Comment: So Logger seems to be a class in java. Do I have to create a Logger object and then hand the flag to it?

Comment: The Java classes (not your classes, the JDK classes like Serializable) use Logger actively. You don't need to create a new Logger to debug the Serializable interface unless you check against code you wrote

Comment: No .... you DON'T add this to logging.properties!  This is nothing to do with that kind of logging. See my Answer for the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are launching a Java app from the command line, you supply it as a JVM command line option.  It must go after the `java` command, and before the classname or the `-jar` option ... whichever you are using.

If you are launching the app from within Eclipse, open the "Run Configurations" wizard, find the config for your application, select the "Program Arguments" panel and add the option to the "JVM Arguments".